# Solr sort on latest upcoming timestamp value on multivalued field

Tags: php, solr

I have a multivalued field for session timings of groups in timestamp. e.g. `session_timings: [1526882026, 1513882026, 1533882026 ]`. My sorting logic is the groups should be listed sorted based on their upcoming session time.

For example, Group A has three `session_timings = [1, 2, 5]`. And Group B also has three `session_timings = [1, 6, 7]`. If current timestamp is 3, then Group A should come first because next session for Group A is on 5, whereas for Group B its 7. Is this possible with solr sorting? Or do I have to use another way to do this? Any help would be great.

Comment: You can sort by the difference between current timestamp and your database timestamps

Comment: how would this work on multivalued fields like this?

Comment: Can you store the last timestamp in a separate column of your documents ?

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR, A group has multiple sessions, so there would multiple sessions timings for a group. So last timestamp would always be different based on current timestamp